# How do I generate a friendly URL in Symfony PHP?

Tags: php, url, seo, symfony1

I always tend to forget these built-in **Symfony** functions for making links.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your goal is to have user-friendly URLs throughout your application, use the following approach:

1) Create a routing rule for your module/action in the application's routing.yml file.  The following example is a routing rule for an action that shows the most recent questions in an application, defaulting to page 1 (using a pager):

```
recent_questions:
   url:    questions/recent/:page
   param:  { module: questions, action: recent, page: 1 }
```

2) Once the routing rule is set, use the `url_for()` helper in your template to format outgoing URLs.

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('questions/recent?page=1') ?>">Recent Questions</a>
```

In this example, the following URL will be constructed: `http://myapp/questions/recent/1.html`.

3) Incoming URLs (requests) will be analyzed by the routing system, and if a pattern match is found in the routing rule configuration, the named wildcards (ie. the `:/page` portion of the URL) will become request parameters.

You can also use the `link_to()` helper to output a URL without using the HTML `<a>` tag.

Comment: Just a nit, but the URL will not be constructed with the .html part unless the application is configured to do so (by default it is not).

Answer (score 1):

This advice is for symfony 1.0. It probably will work for later versions.

**Within your sfAction class**:

string  genUrl($parameters = array(), $absolute = false)

eg. 
$this->getController()->genUrl('yourmodule/youraction?key=value&key2=value', true);

**In a template**:

This will generate a normal link.

string link_to($name, $internal_uri, $options = array());

eg. 
link_to('My link name', 'yourmodule/youraction?key=value&key2=value');

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you actually want a query string with that url, you use this:

```
link_to('My link name', 'yourmodule/youraction?key=value&key2=value',array('query_string'=>'page=2'));
```

Otherwise, it's going to try to route it as part of the url and likely break your action.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate URL directly without define the rule first.

If you want to generate URL in the actions, you can use **generateUrl()** helper:

```
$this->generateUrl('default', array('module'=>'[ModuleName]','action'=>'[ActionName]'))
```

If you want to generate URL in the templates, you can use **url_for()** helper:

```
url_for('[ModuleName]/[ActionName]', $absolute)
```

set $absolute as true/false, dont forget to use echo if you want to display it.

But if you want to make a **link** (something like `<a href=""></a>`), **link_to()** helper will do.